# ASP.NET Membership without using a table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, header, authorization

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application where I want to authorize users to access specific content via roles. These roles will be passed in through the application headers. After exploring ASP.NET membership, it seems like the membership information is normally supposed to be stored in a table, but I do not need/want this. I simply need to take the role from the header when the user accesses the application, and then access it later (ideally) using ASP.NET membership to use data annotations in my models and/or views to control who can see what information.

I apologize if this is sort of ambiguous, I am just not sure where to start since I cannot seem to find an example of someone simply taking the role from the headers without storing this information in a membership table.

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want to store your membership data in a database, where *do* you want to store it?  I imagine you could write a custom membership provider to use whatever mechanism you want to use.

Comment: @David I do not want to store it anywhere. This information is being passed into our application when the user accesses it, so I simply need to get the role from the header when the application is accessed.

Comment: Just implement a custom logic which takes the role from the header.

Comment: It sounds like you don't want to use the built-in authentication/authorization system at all.  So your application shouldn't use it.  Instead, you'd write your own logic to examine the header information in the request and act accordingly.

Comment: @Dexion I can easily get it from the header, but then what do I do with it in my application? I could throw it in the session, but then I don't believe I can use data annotations on my models/controllers to control what is being accessed.

Comment: @David I was hoping there would be a way I could utilize it to take advantage of the data annotations, etc. But I suppose putting the role into a session variable might be the easiest way to accomplish this.

Comment: You can implement a custom attribute on the web level which takes the session variable and checks if the method can be executed or not.

Comment: @Soldat1988: Data annotations are nothing more than attributes, you can write your own to perform your custom logic.